# Get navigation error after ng build --prod in angular 7

Tags: angular

I am working with a very simple angular application.

I have below routing file.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: SelectFrameworkComponent
    }, {
        path: 'angular-4-bootstrap-3',
        component: AngularFourBootstrapThreeComponent
    }
];
```

That is working fine but when I make a build using `ng build --prod` and try to run index.html file locally after changing href to my dist folder `<base href="">`

I am getting this error in console.

```
Unhandled Navigation Error:  main.eac436052bd523dffe9b.js
```

Comment: Paresh Gami, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Simer actually when I upload dist folder to live server that is working.

Comment: Thanks! Paresh Gami, do you have any idea about why it does not work without server? I posted this question regarding the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53626748/why-angular-app-dist-build-needs-to-be-served-on-web-server

Answer (score 2):

Got same issue after added angular router. It seems to have routing problem and found the solution that works for me well. 
Add in index.html

```html
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

instead of

```html
<base href="./">
```

Chaned router configuration which allows me to use hashes in browser link in app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash:true}),
    Bootstrap4FrameworkModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule 
  ],
```

Comment: useHash may solve it but it won't actually resolve the issue if you want to use "Real" urls which are better for SEO and indexing.  Also doesn't help with SSR.

Answer (score 0):

set `useHash: true` as @suhyura mentioned at RouterModule.forRoot

You may also want to set the base href to # as showed below in your index.html

```
<base href="#">
```